# A commutative noetherian ring in which each ideal $I$ is principal and $I^2=I$ must be a finite product of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, noetherian

> **PROBLEM** A commutative noetherian ring $R$ in which each ideal $I$ is principal and $I^2=I$ must be a finite product of fields.

I am lost with the condition $I^2=I$ and the desired result "a finite product of fields". In particular, I totally don't know how to use the condition$I^2=I$? 
Also, I guess this question possibly do with the following question:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1 in which each ideal is prime. Show
>   that $R$ is a field.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe you want to clarify the hypothesis: why need noetherian if "each ideal $I$ is principal"?

Comment: @henry Maybe you mean "each principal ideal is idempotent"?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: A principal ideal $I$ statifying $I^2=I$ is simply an ideal generated by an idempotent. Since every ideal of $R$ is generated by an idempotent, the nilradical of $R$ (which contains nilpotent elements only) must be $(0)$, together  with the Noetherian property, $(0)$ is the intersection of finite many prime ideals. Moreover, since in an integral domain, the only idempotent elements are $0$ and $1$, all the prime ideals of $R$ are maximal.

Comment: @MattSamuel :If you take quotient by a prime ideal, you'll get a integral domain.

Answer (score 3):

As it is already noticed every ideal of $R$ is generated by an idempotent. Now just follow these steps:

1. *Every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal*. If $p_1\subseteq p_2$, and $p_1=(e_1)$, $p_2=(e_2)$, from $e_2(1-e_2)=0\in p_1$ we get $e_2\in p_1$ hence $p_1=p_2$.
2. *$R$ is artinian*.
3. *$R$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of artinian local rings*. This is a consequence of the structure theorem for artinian rings.
4. *In a local ring the only idempotents are $0$ and $1$*.
5. *A commutative ring having only two ideals is a field*.
6. *$R$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of fields*.

Answer (score 2):

By Nakayama's lemma, a principal ideal satisfying $I^2=I$ is generated by an idempotent, and is therefore a direct summand of $R$.

Therefore all ideals are direct summands, meaning that $R$ is semisimple Artinian. By the Artin Wedderburn theorem, such a ring is a finite product of fields.

It's already been pointed out that as stated the Noetherian hypothesis is superfluous, since all ideals are finitely generated already. If you meant that *all principal ideals satisfy $I^2=I$* then the above argument can be adapted in the following way.

You can conclude that all principal ideals are direct summands, therefore $R$ is Von Neumann regular, and a Noetherian VNR ring is semisimple Artinian.

Comment: @user26857 It is hardly more complicated than going through the "zero-dimensional Noetherian ring is Artinian" theorem, and then the structure theorem for Artinian rings. It seems that these two paths are about equal in complexity. It's definitely also a matter of background since in noncommutative algebra AW is much more fundamental than the other two theorems.